Are emojis allowed on this site?
This question is already discussed here, where emojis are seen as noise and several issues of displaying emojis on different devices are seen as a drawback.
How should we handle emojis and are they a reason for editing a post?

Could you mention a post with emoji on this site? I could only notice this question with 1 comment and 1 post revision comment using emoji, but not on the post itself.

my personal view is that whilst I dislike emojis myself, the evolving nature of language has them being used more frequently in general. Creating some kind of filter or rule seems excessive and off putting for people who do like to use them. Since they don't seem to be very prolific here anyway I would defer this in the short term without action.

Thanks for your helpful comments! Yes @AndrewT., these are the only posts using emojis up to now, but they made me curious about their general usage here. Like Attack68, i dislike them too, as emojis do not add any contribution on the text, but may be just confusing or offensive if their interpretation or context is not clear enough. Nevertheless, i think that a guideline or statement in the help center on emojis may be useful for new contributors.

Yes they are allowed, if a post can be improved by editing, it's allowed and even welcome. Of course, what is an improvement can be subjective (spelling errors are objectively bad IMO). At this moment, I'm not aware of any post from which I would remove the emojis. Let's reconsider when emoji-use becomes rampant.
